# Run Python 3 scripts on ArcGIS Server 10.5

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-pro, python-3

Is it possible to run Python 3 scripts on our ArcGIS Server 10.5 running Windows?

I have a script that I want to publish as a geoprocessing tool that exports an .aprx (ArcGIS Pro) file to a PDF using **arcpy.mp** but this is using Python 3.

I see at [Run stand-alone scripts](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/using-conda-with-arcgis-pro.htm) that Python 3 is installed with Pro on the desktop but can't see advice on how to install on your server.

I see [The Python 3 runtime for ArcGIS Server on Linux](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.5/administer/linux/linux-python.htm) but the Windows option is greyed out.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro uses Python 3, ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Server use Python 2.7.  You can run the code on the server (you can have both Python 2.x and 3.x installed at the same time) but I'm fairly confident ArcGIS Server 10.5 will not run ArcGIS Pro code as Server will only run Python 2.7.

Comment: Will it become possible later? If ESRI are using Python 3 with Pro, then I thought you would be able Share a geoprocessing service that contains Python 3 on to your server?

Comment: Unlikely with the 10.x releases of Server.  You may want to look at one of the Esri release road-maps as they will outline what is coming in the future.  If it does happen (that Server supports Python 3),  I believe it will come with it no longer supporting 2.x.

Comment: Server 10.5 does have an internal version of Python3. This is how it can support geoprocessing services (web tools) created from ArcGIS Pro. I dont have a copy of Server 10.5 in front of me to drill down, but its somewhere deep deep down, like C:\Program Files\Server\Framework\ ... down down \ ..similar path to Python you see in Pro

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm not sure your mileage on directly using that Python. Its there only in support of Server. It's not put there as a mechanism to tap directly into. (though I'm pretty sure it'll work just fine)

Comment: @KHibma Interesting - I was (obviously) completely unaware of this! Is there any kind of support and/or docs for this?

Comment: I can't comment on it being supported. I believe the only docs are what @badgerseatfrogs has found and linked in the OP. Based on that, no docs, not officially supported. (I wasn't aware of that Linux Server doc, but there are lots of power users who want to get at the AO via arcpy by using Linux Server. The instructions there seem to indicate support by way of installing Conda.)

Answer (score -1):

Set `PYTHONPATH` to the location of the Python3 libraries.   I found these in `ServerRuntime.pth`.

I tried this on ArcGIS Server 10.5.1, I suspect the Python3 arcpy will match ArcGIS Pro at that point in time.

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\Resources\ArcPy;C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\Resources\ArcToolBox\Scripts;C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin
```

```
cd C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\a
rcgispro-py3
```

```
python.exe

Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017, 21:28:42) [MSC v
.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import arcpy
>>>
```